# ggplot2 change in aspect while changing format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently tried to reproduce [the Crime in Downtown Houston](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Crime-in-Downtown-Houston,-Texas-%3a-Combining-ggplot2-and-Google-Maps), Texas made by David Kahle, in order to reproduce it for another analysis later on.

Everything works well, and I can generate map as I want... However, there is an issue I cannot explain.

When I try to save the file at a larger format (let's say, 4500x1546 instead of the normal 1266x435), the size of the points, axis, title, legend etc. do not automatically adjust : they become way too small.
To illustrate this:

[First image= 1200x435 (normal format), second image= 4500x1546 (adjusted format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0hjh.png),

I observe the same effect with a geom_density plot..

I guess the solution is really trivial, but I didn't find it...

Comment: You probably need to increase the base pointsize in one of the ggplot call or the ggsave call.

Comment: Manually setting a size for each item is the solution I used so far, however, what I am looking for is a way to have it done automatically, no matter what the new format is.

Comment: No, there is a base setting from which all others take their cue. Don't have my ggplot book here today and you could probably look this up in the online help... but it is in the default theme.

Comment: You mean, for example, simply changing the "base_size" in this example : http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/themes  ?

I pretty much used this type of solution so far, however it does not solve my aspect issue since I have to set it differently again when the format change.

And more importantly the changes in theme do not apply to the points or the density line... Which are my principal issue.

Maybe the solution is elsewhere, in the format choice at the beggining for example, or another option in the saving process... I really don't know

Comment: Just just `ggsave`, specifically the `dpi` argument. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a higher resolution png there are two approaches:

1. Increase the size in e.g. inches of the plot
2. Increase the dpi, the number of pixels per inch

You chose the second solution, this makes all the elements smaller, which is expected behavior. If you want to increase the resolution without changing the elements, increase the dpi. This can easily be done using `ggsave`:

```
g = ggplot(...)
# low res png
ggsave("lowres.png", width = 6, height = 6, dpi = 50)
# high res png
ggsave("hires.png", width = 6, height = 6, dpi = 600)
```

In this way there is no need to work with `base_size`.

Comment: I knew the answer was really simple but I struggled to find it...
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can accept answer by pressing the green tickmark, this shows the question was answered.